# Eclipse CDT typeid().name()

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Whenever I use

```
typeid(<some type>).name()
```

in Eclipse CDT, Eclipe's Version of IntelliSense would point out that it does not know the function `name()`. I do include `<typeinfo>`.

Although not a major issue, it is annoying that Eclipse always shows an error in each file that I use `name()` even if the program does compile. Is there any way to tell Eclipse about `name()`?

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example? I tried a simple example where I call `typeid(int).name()` and it's resolved fine for me.

Comment: The entire line that it is used on is this one:

std::cout << typeid(decltype(std::int32_t() + std::declval<T>())).name() << "\n";

Comment: A complete example means the entire file (and its dependencies (not counting standard library headers), although hopefully you've reduced the example so that it doesn't have dependencies besides standard library headers). In this case, the definition of `T` is likely to be highly relevant to your issue.